# Cheat engine change default scan settings

Tags: cheat-engine

I want to change these settings on load

```
{
Scan Type:Exact Value
Value Type: 4bytes
}
```

to these everytime i launch CE

```
{
Scan Type:Value Between
Value Type: float
}
```

Comment: I'm 75% sure that those defaults are hardcoded. However, you can grab the source code from here https://github.com/cheat-engine/cheat-engine and alter/compile it yourself if need be.